# What changes do i need to make to a canvas application to support the Oct 1 deadline

Tags: ruby, facebook, oauth, facebook-authentication, koala

I have a canvas app presently using Koala 1.1.0 and the Javascript SDK. I a have been using the OAuth authentication for months now but when I try and use "ouath:true" in my javascript to display the friend picker I am getting this error:

```
API Error Code: 102
API Error Description: Session key invalid or no longer valid
Error Message: Iframe dialogs must be called with a session key
```

Are there extra migrations I need to turn on within the app settings to get things working? Do I need to be on SSL right now for this to work?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade Koala. [Its Github repository](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) suggests that version 1.2 supports OAuth 2.0 and the new cookie format.

Comment: is that a beta gem or fully released? because when i update the i get 1.1.0 as the most recent version

Comment: According to [a post on the Koala Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/koala-users/Pja03-1a1FQ), version 1.2.0beta4 has been released, and 1.2.0 should be coming sometime this week.